# what is the functionality behind the gmail and orkut login?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, gmail

When I sign in in gmail and I open orkut in the new tab or new window then automatically I am signed in in orkut without entering username and password. How this functioanality works..? And when I sign out from either site, I am signing ou from other site also..  is it done by session handeling or by cookies..? what is the mechanism behind this functionality..??

Answer (score 2):

Both use google's central login system which will store a cookie. When you log out of one it removed the cookie and will log you out from both.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it Single sign-on?

Comment: Yes I think It is a single sign-on. But in single sign on we set cookies. and cookies rely on client side so if we sign out from one account then other should be maintained. but this doesn't happen. we are sign out from other account also.

Comment: ^^ How would the other session maintain? The one you logout would delete the cookie, thus exiting the active session.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is done using **OpenID**. Google serves as the ID provider and Orkut uses that **OpenID**. StackOverflow also utilizes **OpenID**.

[More about **Open ID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

*Edit:* Because Orkut relies on Google's database they might share cookies.